# Prove that $\mathscr{F}=\sigma(\mathscr{A})$, where $\mathscr{C}$ is a countable subfamily of $\mathscr{A}$.

Tags: analysis

Let $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the union of all $\sigma-$algebras $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$, where $\mathscr{C}$ is a countable subfamily of $\mathscr{A}$.Prove that $\mathscr{F}=\sigma(\mathscr{A})$.
I proved that $\mathscr{F}\subset \sigma(\mathscr{A})$ but I don't know how to prove the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we show that $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra:

- $\{\emptyset,X\}=\sigma(\{\emptyset,X\})\subset\mathscr{F}$
- Let $E\in\mathscr{F}$, say $E\in\mathscr{C}$ where $\mathscr C\subset \mathscr A$ is countable. Then $E^c\in\sigma(\{E\}\cup \mathscr C)\subset \mathscr F$ because $\{E\}\cup \mathscr C\subset \mathscr A$ is countable.
- Let $E_n\in \mathscr F$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $n$, pick $\mathscr C_n\subset \mathscr A$ countable such that $E_n\in \sigma(\mathscr C_n)$. Put $\mathscr C:=\bigcup_n \mathscr C_n\subset \mathscr A$. This family is countable, and $\bigcup_n E_n\in \sigma(\mathscr C)\subset \mathscr F$.

If $A\in \mathscr{A}$, then $A\in \sigma(\{A\})\subset \mathscr F$, so $\mathscr A\subset \mathscr F$. Since $\mathscr F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma(\mathscr A)\subset \mathscr F$, as desired.

Comment: @JoséLeonel $E_n\in \sigma(\mathscr{C}_n)\subset \sigma(\mathscr{C})$ and the RHS is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Why $\cup_n E_ \in \sigma(\mathscr{C})$

Comment: @JoséLeonel $\bigcup_n E_n$ is a countable union of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$.

Comment: I know that $E_n \subset \sigma(\mathscr{C}_n) \subset \cup_n \sigma (\mathscr{C}_n)$ But I don't know, why holds the other inclusion

Comment: @JoséLeonel $E_n\in \sigma(\mathscr{C}_n)\subset \sigma(\mathscr{C})$ because $\mathscr{C}_n\subset\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that minimality holds the inclusion. Thank you very much.